# How to give date range in a month & Year format in where clause sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to give date range in where clause like below.. however its not giving correct o/p

```
  declare @StartDate DATETIME,  @EndDate DATETIME   
  set @StartDate='9/01/2011'
  set @EndDate='1/30/2012'
   Select * from mytable Where  MONTH(WT.ToDate) >= MONTH(@StartDate) AND MONTH(WT.ToDate) <=MONTH(@Enddate)
   AND YEAR(WT.ToDate)>= YEAR(@StartDate) AND YEAR(WT.ToDate) <=YEAR(@Enddate)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is WT.ToDate, What WT is referring to?

it should be.

```
  declare @StartDate DATETIME,  @EndDate DATETIME   
  set @StartDate='9/01/2011'
  set @EndDate='1/30/2012'
   Select * from mytable as WT Where MONTH(WT.ToDate) >= MONTH(@StartDate) AND MONTH(WT.ToDate) <=MONTH(@Enddate)
   AND YEAR(WT.ToDate)>= YEAR(@StartDate) AND YEAR(WT.ToDate) <=YEAR(@Enddate)
```

Comment: You can also use the BETWEEN operator, it's essentially the same thing, but I think makes it easier to read:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187922.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note I've changed the format you've specified the dates in to avoid any risk of misinterpretation (now yyyyMMdd).

Secondly, try a clause like this:

```
declare @StartDate DATETIME,  @EndDate DATETIME   
set @StartDate='20110901'
set @EndDate='20120130'

Select * 
from mytable 
Where  WT.ToDate >= @StartDate AND WT.ToDate < @EndDate
```

Note, this will not return rows for 30 Jan 2012, so just tweak your @EndDate as appropriate